# Splitting a String by Space in R

Tags: r, regex

Let say I have below string -

```
Str = "15 1,270.00 19050 104.77 40.36 2020070 Rolling IN303028 - 63965276"
```

Now I want to split above string based on `space` however it should not split last phrase i.e. `'IN303028 - 63965276'`. So I tried to use -

```
strsplit(Str, " ")
```

But this is also splitting the last phrase. Is there any way to splitting by `space` but excluding the pattern of `'IN303028 - 63965276'` i.e. if two consecutive `spaces` contains a `hyphen` then it should exclude that part.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could make a regex lookaround to check for spaces after character that are not a `-` (`[^-]`) and the characters that are after the spaces are not `-`

```
strsplit(Str, "(?<=[^-]) (?=[^-])", perl = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "15"                  "1,270.00"            "19050"               "104.77"              "40.36"               "2020070"            
#[7] "Rolling"             "IN303028 - 63965276"
```

---

Or use `*SKIP` `*FAIL` to not consider the spaces where there are `-`

```
strsplit(Str, " - (*SKIP)(*F)| ", perl = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "15"                  "1,270.00"            "19050"               "104.77"              "40.36"               "2020070"            
#[7] "Rolling"             "IN303028 - 63965276"
```

Comment: This is perfect. Would you please explain the pattern which you applied i.e. "(?<=[^-]) (?=[^-])"

Comment: @Bogaso I added some explanation

Comment: @Bogaso added one more solution.  Can you please check if that helps

Comment: In #1 it would perhaps be better to use negative lookarounds, to accomodate the possibility of multiple contiguous spaces. [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/5AvXtY/1/) vs [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/5AvXtY/2/).

Comment: Thanks, my initial solution was with negative lookaround, but I found an edge case and removed it

Comment: What was the edge case?